# PrimeNG Calendar (p-calendar) won't reset manual input

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, primeng

I am using `p-calendar` in my Angular2 application and I'm experiencing some strange behaviour. If I insert the date value with the help of the calendar widget, it will successfully reset after I'm caling the `.reset()` function on my form group. The problem I'm getting is that when user enters the date by hand into the calendar input field, it won't get cleared after calling `.reset()`. If I try to fetch the value of the field it will return the correct default value (null), but input field is still showing the previously inserted value, that was already submitted.

I am using PrimeNG **2.0.6**.

Is there anything I can do to reset the value stuck in input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after some hours of research and tries in many ways I just found my solution and I hope it will help others. The solution is simple and works for me:

Html

```
<button class="button button-3 button-3a clear" (click)="clearfilter();">
 <i class="fa fa-close"></i> {{'Clear Filters' | translate}}
</button>
<p-table #dt [columns]="cols" 
             [value]="profitsConfig" 
             [rows]="10" 
             [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20,50,100]"
             [paginator]="true" 
             [resizableColumns]="true" 
             columnResizeMode="expand" 
             [scrollable]="true"
             [(selection)]="mySelection" 
             selectionMode="multiple" 
             exportFilename="ProfitsConfig"
             [showCurrentPageReport]="true" 
             currentPageReportTemplate="Total: {{dt.totalRecords}}">
    ...
<p-calendar #createCalendar appendTo="body" 
            [(ngModel)]="rangeDatesCreate" 
            *ngSwitchCase="'createdate'"
            selectionMode="range" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" 
            placeholder="dd/mm/yy - dd/mm/yy"
            (onSelect)="dt.filter($event,col.field, 'dateRangeFilter')" 
            [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true"
            yearRange="1990:2050" [readonlyInput]="true">
</p-calendar>
```

And when I call the function to clear all my filters:

TypeScript

```
rangeDatesCreate: Date[];

constructor(){}

clearfilter() {
  this.rangeDatesCreate = null;
  ....
}
```

So I just set to `null` the value that is bound with `[(ngModel)]`. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (workaround). I used ngIf to hide and show form after submiting data. This seems to trigger the field to reset it's value properly.